# How to do OAuth2 with mobile using cordova (framework7)?

Tags: node.js, cordova, mobile, oauth-2.0, html-framework-7

When i run the framework7 (basically cordova inside) with "start dev" => on browser it works.
I'm using "@bity/oauth2-auth-code-pkce": "^2.13.0"

Switching it to android (my app also needs to work for ios) doesn't work anymore. I guess thats cause the redirectUrl which is localhost on browser doesn't suit (no way back from OAuth-Server back to app (not the browser).

I was told to use "custom scheme" so i installed cordova-plugin-customurlscheme too, but it doesn't help when i say redirectUrl = "myChoosenSchemeName://" or something similar.

Am I on the right track? Can someone please tell me what to do to get OAuth2 Server happy with my app (the server responses with "invalid url").

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track. Have you updated your redirectURI on the server and/or initialized the customurlscheme with --variable URL_SCHEME=fooScheme?

Comment: well, i installed it with this "--variable URL_SCHEME=myChoosenName" it said, OK. but i doubt this really working, cause simple link <f7-link external href="myChoosenName//noExists"> not bring any 404 error.

Comment: If that link (with ://) works on mobile you should be good to go. You could also try 'cordova-plugin-oidc-basic' which is what I am currently using